# How to find $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{(n+1)^{k}+(-n)^{l}}{(n-1)^{k}-n^{l}}$ for $k,l\in\mathbb{N}$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

How to find $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{(n+1)^{k}+(-n)^{l}}{(n-1)^{k}-n^{l}}$$ $k,l\in\mathbb{N}$.

I know that it is 1: for $k>l$ 
for $k < l$ :
$$(-1)^{1+l}$$

for k=l odd: -1
for k=l even : $$-\infty$$

But I do not know how to get it. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Use binomial theorem and look on higher order of $n$. Or use $(n+1)^k=n^k \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^k$ and use $(1+x)^k \sim \text{something}$ when $x\to 0$.

Comment: What is $(-n)^\ell$ when $\ell$ is real and not integer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each condition you should use binomial expansion and then devide the numerator and denominator by the higher order of $n$ and then use $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}$ for the fraction.